# How to duplicate a report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

[image]I am trying to duplicate a report that a[image]lready exists already with the exact formatting.

I don't see an option to duplicate or copy a report.

Answer (score 0):

Save a copy (File->Save As) with a new name, or save in a new location with the same name.